# Cancel button only clears the recipient number and does not return back to app?

Tags: swift, xcode7

The cancel button only clears the recipient phone number but does not go back to the app?  Any help?  Here is the code I'm currently using.....

import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtMsg: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPhone: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}

@IBAction func sndSMS(sender: AnyObject) {

    txtMsg.resignFirstResponder()
    txtPhone.resignFirstResponder()

    let msgVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    msgVC.body = txtMsg.text!
    msgVC.recipients = ["1-206-724-8288"]
    msgVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(msgVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What cancel button? Can you please give more context to your question?

Comment: Im building an app that uses the iPhone native SMS messaging screen, the user can enter text and send the text however the cancel button only clears the recipient number but does not actually cancel the text and return back to the app.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the delegate but you are not implementing the method listed here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontrollerdelegate/1614061-messagecomposeviewcontroller

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
              didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult)
```

Comment: Kyle Browning - Thanks for the feedback, i did have the method listed but it may not have been listed in the above code.  except my code looked like this

Comment: func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
              didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult)

Comment: I add the "_" before controller but it gives me an error, is there where i place a command?